# In Server 2012, how do I log into the "old" administrator account?

Tags: windows-server-2012, domain, windows-server-essentials

Here's a quick run down of what I did:

1. Installed Windows Server Essentials Experience feature/role
2. Played around with it
3. Uninstalled it
4. Demoted the server as the domain controller
5. Rebooted
6. Now my server has two administrator accounts. "Administrator" and "Administrator.ComputerName"

However, I want to log into administrator.computername because now my desktop and start screen are defaulted back to their factory originals and none of my shortcuts and stuff are there.

How do I accomplish this? Or at least, migrate everything?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles across this question and has the same issue, I found a link with a fix by the poster "BSOD"

http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/351634-recreating-domain-user-profile-now-logging-into-temp-profile

To better describe my problem, when I logged in as administrator I was actually getting a TEMP profile every time. This resolved it.